# log4net - how to log only errors from certain namespace

Tags: .net, logging, filter, namespaces, log4net

is there any way to log in log4net all messages from certain namespace but only errors from every other namespace?

I tried it by *LoggerMatchFilter*, but it seems that this filter cannot operate with log levels.

Comment: You could use both a LoggerMatchFilter and a LevelMatchFilter as outlined in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650399/how-to-and-log4net-filters-together)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your loggername is based on the class name, then you just set the root level to Error and create a new logger in your configuration file for your namespace and set its level to ALL,

ie, something like

```
    <root>
        <level value="ERROR" />
        <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
    </root>

    <logger name="MyNameSpace">
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
    </logger>
```